# Lebesgue theorem - calculate the limit of the integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$$\mbox{Let } f:X\to[0,\infty] \mbox{ and} \int fd\mu=c \mbox{ and we know that } 0<c<\infty \mbox{ and } 0<\alpha<\infty$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\int {n\ln\left[1+\left[{{f(x)}\over{n}}\right]^{\alpha}\right]}}d\mu(x) $$ The instruction says to consider cases separately. $$\mbox{ So I calculated that for } \alpha=1 \to \lim_{n\to\infty} {\int {n\ln\left[1+{{f(x)}\over{n}}\right]}}d\mu(x) = c$$ But I have a problem with calculating this integral for: $$0<\alpha<1 \mbox{ and } 1<\alpha<\infty$$Does anyone know how to solve this for the other two cases?

Answer (score 2):

You would want to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem, in fact
$$n\ln{\left[1+{\frac{f(x)}{n}}\right]^{\alpha}} = \alpha n \ln\left[1+{\frac{f(x)}{n}}\right] \le \alpha n {\frac{f(x)}{n}} = \alpha f(x)$$
and it is integrable since
$$\int |\alpha f(x)|d\mu = \alpha \int f(x) = \alpha c < +\infty .$$

So now we apply the DCT to say
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\int {n\ln\left[1+{{f(x)}\over{n}}\right]^{\alpha}}}d\mu(x) = {\int \lim_{n\to\infty}{n\ln\left[1+{{f(x)}\over{n}}\right]^{\alpha}}}d\mu(x)$$$$ = {\int \lim_{n\to\infty}{\alpha \ln\left[1+{{f(x)}\over{n}}\right]^n dx= \int \alpha \ln\Big[e^{f(x)}}}\Big]d\mu(x) = $$
$$= \int \alpha f(x) dx = \alpha \int f(x) dx = \alpha c.$$

Comment: Sorry for the integral error, I wrote the alpha in the wrong place..